# Codeigniter xss filtering and url link

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a textarea field where users can post link and text, after applying XSS filtering the URL becomes unclickable. Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem recently and was going to look at using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) with CI - It might be overkill for what you want but it wouldn't hurt to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see many solutions for this; CI's `xss_clean` method is quite extensive, and if you think at it twice you'll see a contradiction:

`xss_clean` is meant to provide security against XSS, a form of which is using malicious links; but you still want to have your links active and working, thus opening you to XSS injections...

My suggestion is picking one of the following options:

1. Forget about using links, and be safe & sound but with no clickable urls;
2. Allow URLs using a different filtering technique; you need to read more on that, I'm no expert whatsoever, but the task would be quite tricky and hard; but be **very careful**, don't trust excessively single regexes, but apply different filters (like blacklisting, characters stripping, encoding/decoding, and so on);
3. Full xss clean the input, and tell your users that if they want to have clickable links, they must provide them in a different field. On that, apply a custom validation (still tricky but not as point 2) ) that makes them safe agains XSS